# In SQL Server, are INSERTs from outer transactions visible to inner transactions' SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

If I call a stored procedure from within a stored procedure, both of which begin and commit transactions, will the inner one be able to see `INSERT`'s that have been performed, but not committed, by the outer procedure? More generally, how is scope handled with nested procedures and transactions? Most of what I can find is about rollbacks and error handling, which I'm not quite concerned with yet.

I have an application that basically does the following, and it's not finding the newly inserted record from within the inner procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1 AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO T1 (Data) VALUES (100)
        EXEC Proc2
    COMMIT
END

CREATE PROCEDURE Proc2 AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE Data = 100 )
            PRINT 'Record does not exist.'
    COMMIT
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not support nested transactions.  When you do a second `begin transaction`, all that happens is that the `@@TRANCOUNT` variable is increased.  A commit that does not reduce the `@@TRANCOUNT` to zero [does nothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx).

So "inner" transactions are in fact part of the "one" transaction.  They can see uncommitted changes from the calling procedure.

If I run your code on my machine, `Proc2` is able to see the record inserted by `Proc1` just fine.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted to know, even if it doesn't solve my problem. I'll look for the bug in my code elsewhere, then. Thanks! :)